# Delegate event in unity

Tags: c#, events, delegates, unity-game-engine

I want when the button has been clicked, it will show some GUI button on it. I already tried the delegate, but the event is not fired (I mean the GUI button is not shown).

Here is the code that I am using:

The code below is to show the GUI button when I run the game.

```
public class IItemDatabase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void Action(); // Set the event for the button

    public static event Action onClicked; // The event for when the button has been clicked

    protected virtual void OnGUI()
    {
        // Call the SetStyle method
        SetStyle();

        // Set the GUIContent as the tooltip
        GUIContent buttonText = new GUIContent("Open Shop");

        // Set the GUIContent as the tooltip
        GUIContent buttonTexts = new GUIContent("Open Inventory");

        // This GUILayoutUtility is useful because it is to fit the content
        Rect buttonGUI = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(buttonText, "Button");

        // This GUILayoutUtility is useful because it is to fit the content
        Rect buttonGUIs = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(buttonTexts, "Button");

        // Set where have to the Rect displayed
        buttonGUI.x = 5;
        buttonGUI.y = Screen.height - 25;

        // Set where have to the Rect displayed
        buttonGUIs.x = 125;
        buttonGUIs.y = Screen.height - 25;

        // If the button has been clicked

        if (GUI.Button(buttonGUI, buttonText, style))
        {
            if (onClicked != null)
            {
                onClicked();
            }
        }

        if (GUI.Button(buttonGUIs, buttonTexts, style))
        {
            if (onClicked != null)
            {
                onClicked();
            }
        }

        // End of the clicked button event
    }
}
```

And here is the I want it to display when the button has been clicked:

```
public class IInventory : MonoBehaviour 
{

    protected virtual void OnEnable()
    {
        IItemDatabase.onClicked += DoGUI;
    }

    protected virtual void OnDisable()
    {
        IItemDatabase.onClicked -= DoGUI;
    }

    protected virtual void DoGUI()
    {
       Rect slotRect = new Rect(x * 35 + (Screen.width / 3) + 50, y * 35 + (Screen.height / 3) - 10, 30, 30);
                GUI.Box(slotRect, GUIContent.none);
    }
}
```

But when I clicked the button that it suppose to fired the DoGUI() in IInventory class, it does not run the function.

How do I solve this?

Thank you.

Your answer much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not the event or the delegate, but a misunderstanding on how `OnGUI()` works.

The [`OnGUI()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html) method might be called several times per frame, but your `onClicked` event will only be called once after you clicked the button. So your Inventory is only visible for a few milliseconds.

There are several ways to solve the problem. Your goal is to call `DoGUI()` during every `OnGUI()` call as long as you want the inventory to be shown. You could introduce a boolean that saves the state of the inventory menu and decides whether the menu should be visible or not. If you want your `Open Inventory` button to toggle the menu, you could try something like that

```
public class IItemDatabase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Action onClicked; // The event for when the button has been clicked

    private bool showInventory = false;

    protected virtual void OnGUI()
    {
        // I removed your other code to simplify the example

        if (GUI.Button("Open Inventory"))
        {
            // toggle the status
            showInventory = !showInventory
        }

        if (showInventory && onClicked != null)
        {
            onClicked();
        }

    }
}
```

If you want to keep the event depends on your application. If you keep it, I would rename it to `showInventoryGUI` or something similar to better reflect its intention. On the other hand you could simply remove the event and just call the method `IInventory.DoGUI()` directly.

Comment: So, what should I do sir in order to fix this?

Sorry for the late reply.

Thank you

Comment: @Kaoru I added an example of a possible solution

Comment: Solved! Thank you sir! I did it in another way without using delegate.. Thank you